# How to generate unique random number from 00001 and maintain serial in Codeigniter MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know it's a quite common question. But I have got no solution for CodeIgniter.

I use below MySQL code. I want to know how can I use this code directly in Codeigniter view. It shows error.

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 99999) AS random_num
FROM glf_invoice 
WHERE "random_num" NOT IN (SELECT patient_reg FROM glf_invoice)
LIMIT 1
```

This code shows a number of 5 digits in `phpmyadmin` SQL.

And how can I maintain serial from 00001 to 00002...

Comment: "_It shows error._" What would that error be?

Comment: set the column to auto increment with the value => 00001

Comment: Thanks @LavishTyagi

Answer (score 0):

On the ID column, set it to "Auto Increment". It may be noted down as "A_I".